# What is the 'unit of output time' when default_timer is used from timer module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I'm trying to find the time taken by this program ("Fibonacci series") to run.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
n=int(input())
start = timer()
li=[0,1,1]
if n==1:
    print(li[0])
elif n==2 or n==3:
    print(li[1])
else:
    for i in range(n-3):
        x=li[-1]+li[-2]
        li.append(x)
print(li[-1])
print("{}".format(timer()-start))
```

I give the input
`100`
and I get the output as

```
218922995834555169026
0.0004896000000371714
```

The first line is the Fibonacci answer and the second line is the time taken, I want to know what is the unit of this time? '0.0004896000000371714' what this value means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in seconds; see docs: the default timer usually points to the [time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) function. You can use [time.perf_counter_ns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) for nanoseconds.

If you inspect `timer` you will see it is `<function time.perf_counter>` or some similar result.